# Что не так делаю в передаче массива из js в php, записать, а затем преобразовать

Tags: javascript, php

```
function FormAdd(obj, el = new FormData()) {
    for (let key in obj)
        el.append(key, obj[key]);
    return el;
};

navigator.sendBeacon('/ajax/', FormAdd({md:'v', w:JSON.stringify({22:2})}))
```

В php, переменная $_POST['w'] содержит строчку

```
{\"22\":2}
```

Данный массив в виде строчки, необходимо записать в бд. То есть необходимо пропустить через

```
serialize($_POST['w'])
```

А затем взять из бд и преобразовать в массив, через unserialize

Во первых ошибка в том, что строчку пропускаю через serialize, то есть необходимо сперва строчку преобразовать в массив.

И тут что уже не пробовал, нечего не выходит. То ли из-за слешей, то ли еще из-за чего. Хелп.

Comment: А зачем применять `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: у вас и так JSON-строка, зачем ее еще в serialize заворачивать?

Comment: Достаточно отправить запрос с нужными заголовками Accept и Content-Type, и не нужно будет проводить никаких дополнительных манипуляций с JSON

Comment: Можно пример, с какими заголовками?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов `Accept: application/json` и `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Можно  пример как отправить и принять массив в php?

Comment: Оффтоп. Я бы не использовал sendBeacon, например в Firefox на Ubuntu эта штука отключена (`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: navigator.sendBeacon is not a function`).

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов На клиенте просто отправляете json, как он есть (никаких `Stringify` не нужно, вы передаете объект а не строку). На сервере Вы просто получаете массив как он есть через $_POST. т.е отправленный `{ data: 'test' }` можно получить по `$_POST['data']`. Само собой, если заголовки выставлены правильно.

Comment: Ничего  не получается, можно при пример того как вы это делаете?

Comment: php ничего автоматом из json преобразовывать не будет. Отправляйте из js через `FormData()`, тогда в php можете принимать через `$_POST`